# how to develop desktop notification for my web Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am developing one desktop application which allow to create notification on desktop bar when this application is in running mode and also new customer come into system. for-that, i made one WCF service which can communicate with database  and also build desktop application  this requirement works fine. now i want to make one icon which turn into  red when new count is coming into system otherwise it will remain red.

C# Code:

```
protected void Displaynotify()
{
    try
    {
        int i=0, j=1;
        long k = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            ServiceReference1.Service1Client vc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            p = vc.GetNotoficationCnt();
            if (k != p)
            {
                notifyIcon1.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Path.GetFullPath(@"E:\TerryBerry_Current_Working_Cpy\branches\NotificationDeskopApplication\image\Terryberry_weblogo.ico"));
                notifyIcon1.Text = "Export Datatable Utlity";
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Your Lead Count is:" + p + "";
                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Click Here to see details";
                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(100);
                k = p;
            }
            else
            {   
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem exactly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: i just want to change desktop icon color according to new customer come into my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the NotifyIcon.Icon property to the new icon to change it.